# Parse backticks inside quoted strings antlr4

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I'm developing a program that parses and executes commands similar to bash. I want to obtain the string within the backticks that might be contained in either single or double quotes. For example, I want the string "echo hello", from the input string 'echo "`echo hello`" so I can process it first.

Is it possible to get the parsed string directly from antlr, or should I handle this command substitution functionality within my actual program? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy: first do a first parse run for the entire input. Find the string tokens and feed them again to your lexer. You have to have a rule that matches backtick strings, to make this work. In the second lexer run you get all embedded backtick delimited strings.

Alternatively, just iterate over the strings from the first run and look for a start back tick, then search for the next backtick as the second delimiter. Do that as often as you find more back ticks.